# How to restore default condition handling for EXEC CICS in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, cics

After execution of a CICS command how do I restore the default handler if I've set a condition handler?

```
           EXEC CICS HANDLE CONDITION
                     ERROR(X0000-GEN-ERR-PARA)
           END-EXEC.

           EXEC CICS READQ TS                                          
                ITEM(1)
                QUEUE(UNIQNAME)
                INTO(DATA)
                LENGTH(LDATA)                   
           END-EXEC.
```

I can add an IGNORE but this is not the same:

```
           EXEC CICS IGNORE CONDITION 
                     ERROR        
           END-EXEC.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the API-documentation for `HANDLE CONDITION`:

> If you omit the label parameter, any HANDLE CONDITION command for the condition is deactivated, and the default action is taken if the condition occurs.

it should be sufficient to do

```
       EXEC CICS HANDLE CONDITION
                 ERROR
       END-EXEC.
```

to restore the default condition-handling.